# Registry Changes not being saved

Tags: windows-xp

I've been looking at a couple of customer machines and trying to figure out why registry changes aren't being persisted when the machine is powercycled (powerloss etc).

These machines aren't on a domain and they are setup with just basic automatic logon of a user.

(all the below performed as a local administrator)

If you go in with Regedit and make a change on the machine exit and then come back it's all ok.

If you go in with Regedit and make a change then restart the machine the change is there when you come back.

If you make a change with Regedit, Exit regedit and reopen to check it's still there, but if the machine then losses power the registry change is lost.

Is there something I can look at see why these changes are not being stored to the registry?

I know that some of the machines are XPsp2, and XPsp3. I can't exactly pin as to why it is being lost. (And yes I have asked the customer to Update their machines to sp3 and patches etc).

The main keys being edited are under the `HKLM` tree namely `HKLM/Software`.

Comment: Are the registry changes being performed under HKLM or HKCU? If it's HKCU you'd get this behaviour if you're using a mandatory profile or if the user has been logged on with a temporary profile.

Comment: HKLM (see edits). Is there a way to see if they have a Temp Profile in use?

Comment: If the keys are under HKLM then a temporary profile shouldn't affect this (with a temporary profile any changes to the HKCU hive are discarded at logoff).

Comment: Could the machines be using [SteadyState](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState) or a similar technology to return the machines to their previous state at every boot?

Comment: I don't think anything special is running on them (at least that i can see in ProcessExplorer). If you do the graceful restart, everything is fine, it's only if you lose power that you lose the setting